# Reading a file in C on Linux

Tags: c, linux

How do I read a file into a string on Linux in C?
I came up with some code, but it's not working, and idk why. fgetc() always returns -1.

The file structure is something like this

```
.:
Files/
main.c
makefile

./Files:
test
```

Contents of `main.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fileLength(const char filePath[]);
void readFile(const char filePath[], char* outString);

int main()
{
    char fileContents[fileLength("Files/test")];
    readFile("Files/test", &fileContents);
    printf("DEBUG: Address of fileContents is 0x%x\n", &fileContents);
    printf("File contents:\n%s\n", fileContents);
    
    return 0;
}

int fileLength(const char filePath[])
{
    //Open the file
    FILE* file;
    
    if ((file = fopen(filePath, "r")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR: File (%s) cannot be opened.\n", filePath);
        return -1;
    }
    
    //Find the length
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    return ftell(file);
}

void readFile(const char filePath[], char* outString)
{
    FILE* file;
    
    //File reading
    printf("DEBUG: File path is %s\n", filePath);
    if ((file = fopen(filePath, "r")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR: File (%s) cannot be opened.\n", filePath);
        exit(1);
    }
    
    //Get length of file and allocate the according amount of memory
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    int fileLength = ftell(file);
    printf("DEBUG: File length is %i\n", fileLength);
    
    //Allocate string
    char fileContent[fileLength];
    
    //Read file to string
    printf("DEBUG: File contents as digits:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < fileLength; i++)
    {
        fileContent[i] = fgetc(file);
        printf("%d ", fileContent[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("DEBUG: Contents of file are:\n%s\n", fileContent);
    fclose(file);
    
    printf("DEBUG: outString is pointing to 0x%x\n", outString);
    
    *outString = fileContent;
}
```

The output is usually just a bunch of question mark diamond things (running in terminal) that match the length of the file with a few other random chars thrown in at the end. The chars at the end change every time the program is run.

Comment: `fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);` causes the file pointer to be at the end of the file. That's why `fgetc` fails. Call `rewind` or `fopen` the file again after getting the file length. Also, note that the `fileLength` function causes resource leaks as it does not `fclose` the file.

Comment: Also, `char fileContent[fileLength];` does not end up being a valid string as it is not NUL terminated. Make it one byte larger and ensure last byte is set to 0.

Comment: You need to look at your whole code - you use fileLength to get the size but then readFile does the same thing anyway - and won't actually send what it read back to main(). Plus you never close any of the files you open.

Comment: I did what kaylum said and the debug print works but not the "File contents:\n%s\n" in main(), am I doing something wrong with the assignment?

Comment: `*outString = fileContent;` doesn't do what you think it does. In fact, the compiler should warn you about that. You should not be making a local `fileContent` array. Write directly into `outString` instead.

Answer (score 0):

kaylum was right, the solution was to:

- `rewind()` after finding the file length in `readFile()`
- remember to `fclose()` when done
- write directly to `outString` instead of using `fileContent`

The final code of `main.c` comes out to be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fileLength(const char filePath[]);
void readFile(const char filePath[], char* outString);

int main()
{
    char fileContents[fileLength("Files/test")];
    readFile("Files/test", &fileContents);
    printf("File contents:\n%s\n", fileContents);
    
    return 0;
}

int fileLength(const char filePath[])
{
    //Open the file
    FILE* file;
    
    if ((file = fopen(filePath, "r")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR: File (%s) cannot be opened.\n", filePath);
        return -1;
    }
    
    //Find the length
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    int length = ftell(file);
    fclose(file);
    return length;
}

void readFile(const char filePath[], char* outString)
{
    FILE* file;
    
    //File reading
    if ((file = fopen(filePath, "r")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR: File (%s) cannot be opened.\n", filePath);
        exit(1);
    }
    
    //Get length of file and allocate the according amount of memory
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    int fileLength = ftell(file);
    rewind(file);
    
    //Read file to string
    for (int i = 0; i < fileLength; i++)
        outString[i] = fgetc(file);
    fclose(file);
}
```